# sql multi count from different different table

Tags: mysql, sql

HOW TO Get all the leads and hits of a referer?

Table : hits_log

```
+-----------+----------+
| topic     | referer  |
+-----------+----------+
| topic0614 | xxxxxxxx |
| topic0614 | xxxxxxxx |
| topic0615 | zzzzz    |
| topic0615 | yyyyyy   |
| topic0614 | xxxxxxxx |
| topic0614 | xxxxxxxx |
| topic0615 | zzzzz    |
| topic0615 | yyyyyy   |
| topic0614 | yyyyyy   |
| topic0614 | yyyyyy   |
| topic0615 | zzzzz    |
| topic0615 | yyyyyy   |
+-----------+----------+
```

Table : leads_log

```
+-----------+----------+
| topic     | referer  |
+-----------+----------+
| topic0614 | xxxxxxxx |
| topic0614 | xxxxxxxx |
| topic0614 | xxxxxxxx |
| topic0615 | zzzzz    |
| topic0615 | yyyyyy   |
| topic0614 | xxxxxxxx |
| topic0615 | zzzzz    |
| topic0614 | yyyyyy   |
+-----------+----------+
```

I want the result like this
If search with topic `topic0614`

```
+-----------+----------+------------+
| referer   | hits     | leads      |
+-----------+----------+------------+
| xxxxxxxx  | 4        | 4          |
| yyyyyy    | 2        | 1          |
+-----------+----------+------------+
```

i have tried

```
SELECT h.referer, COUNT(h.referer)  as hits, COUNT(l.referer)  as leads FROM `hits_log` h ,`leads_log` l
WHERE h.topic='topic0614' and h.referer=l.referer
GROUP BY h.referer
```

but it didn't work

can any one help me out?      Thank You.

Comment: Why does `xxxxxxxx` have 5 leads in your sample output? I only see 4 in the `leads_log` table. And why is `yyyyyy` only 1, there are 2 in the `leads_log` table.

Comment: i have no of hits from hit_log and no of leads from leads log storing independently so it is like that

Comment: But `xxxxxxxx` is only in 4 rows of `hits_log`, why do you have `5` in the results?

Comment: When counting in `leads_log`, you don't say to only count `topic0614`. So my answer counts all matching referers.

Comment: oops sry that was my mistake see Edited it is 4 not 5

Comment: You appear to have no PK. In relational data, this is a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to group each table separately in a subquery. If you do the count in the main query, you're counting the results of the cross-product, which causes multiplication.

```
SELECT h.referer, hits, leads
FROM (SELECT referer, COUNT(*) AS hits
      FROM hits_log
      WHERE topic = 'topic0614'
      GROUP BY referer) AS h
JOIN (SELECT referer, COUNT(*) AS leads
      FROM leads_log
      GROUP BY referer) AS l
ON h.referer = l.referer
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6f064/1)

Maybe this is actually what you want. It restricts both hits and leads to a specific topic, and will include referers with zero count in either table.

```
SELECT referer, MAX(hits) AS hits, MAX(leads) AS leads
FROM (SELECT referer, COUNT(*) AS hits, 0 as leads
      FROM hits_log
      WHERE topic = 'topic0614'
      GROUP BY referer
      UNION
      SELECT referer, 0 AS hits, COUNT(*) as leads
      FROM leads_log
      WHERE topic = 'topic0614'
      GROUP BY referer) AS x
GROUP BY referer
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2a216/4)

Comment: it is only giving one single row if two referer against a single topic it is not giving 2nd row

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Take a look at my sqlfiddle demo. I'm not totally sure what you really want, because your sample output doesn't seem to match the sample input -- see my question in the comments.

Comment: All the hits for `topic0614` have referer `xxxxxxxx` in your fiddle, so there's no other `h.referer`.

Comment: See the query I just added.